# Solve $x' = 2-4t-x+tx^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $x(t)\equiv 2$ be one of solution following differential equation: 
$$x' = 2-4t-x+tx^2$$
Using $y(t) = \frac{1}{x(t)}$ find general solution.

I think that $x'(t) = y'(t) \ln|y(t)| $ so we have:

$$ y'(t) \ln|y(t)| = 2-4t - \frac{1}{y} + t \frac{1}{y^2}$$.

I'm wrong or I don't know how can I solve it.

Comment: By the Maple commands $$with(DEtools): odeadvisor((D(x))(t) = 2-4*t-x(t)+t*x(t)^2) $$[_Riccati] $$ $$ we find the type of the ODE under consideration. Making use of it, we find the general solution by $$dsolve((D(x))(t) = 2-4*t-x(t)+t*x(t)^2, [Riccati], useInt) $$ $$x \left( t \right) =2-{\frac {{{\rm e}^{\int \!-1{dt}+4\,\int \!t{dt}}
}}{\int \!{{\rm e}^{\int \!-1{dt}+4\,\int \!t{dt}}}t{dt}-{\it \_C1}}}
 $$

Comment: $x=1/y$, so $x'=-y'/y^2$

Answer (score 1):

The nonlinear DE:
$$x'=P(t)+Q(t)x+R(t)x^2$$ is called [Ricatti's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation) equation. If $x_1(t)$ is a *known* particular solution of above ODE (as you're given $x(t)=2$), then a family of solutions can be given by $$x(t)=x_1(t)+u(t)$$ where $u(t)$ is a solution of the following associated OE:
$$u'(t)-(Q+2x_1R)u(t)=Ru^2(t)$$ which is a [Bernoulli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation) equation. This latter OE is easier than the original one and can be reduced to the linear equation: $$w'(t)+(Q+2x_1R)w(t)=-R$$. I suggest you to take a look at other answer. Please ask me if you have any questions.

Comment: This needs a TU ("$\uparrow$")!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

Substitute $x(t)$ by $z(t)+2$, $z=x-2$ first:

$z' = 2-4t-z-2+tz^2 + 4zt + 4t = -z+tz^2+4zt$

Now substitute $y=1/z$ so $-y'/y^2 = z'$

$-y' = (4t-1)y + t$

This seems easier to attack.